# Firefox and Edge can't connect to Quickblox Chat

Tags: javascript, websocket, chat, quickblox

This issue is limited to Firefox and Edge while Chrome works fine. Consider that my end goal is to do audio/video chat, not textual chat.

The same error is thrown by the API when connection is attempted:

```
{ code: 422, status: "error", detail: "Status.CONNFAIL - The connection attempt failed", message: "Unprocessable Entity" }
consultations:389:29
```

Firefox shows this message in log:

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://chat.quickblox.com:5291/.
```

Edge shows this:

```
XML5632: Only one root element is allowed.
SCRIPT12030: SCRIPT12030: WebSocket Error: Network Error 12030, The connection with the server was terminated abnormally
```

The following syntax is being followed:

```
QB.init(applicationSessionToken, appId, {})

QB.chat.connect({
        userId: QB.chat.helpers.getUserJid( '{{ $userQuickBlox->quickBloxId }}', 75452),
        password: '{{ $userQuickBlox->password }}',
    }, function(err, roster) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

**Edit 1:**

Fiddler posts identical output for Firefox and Edge:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Origin: https://cmed-web.vantagedigital.net
Host: chat.quickblox.com:5291
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 5xM/G6qmjyskDdYfizDhWA==
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: xmpp

DNT: 1
```

While chrome has a somewhat different makeup:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Origin: https://cmed-web.vantagedigital.net
Host: chat.quickblox.com:5291
Connection: Upgrade
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: rnICPLwETXQWapHTwCheFg==
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: xmpp

Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Pragma: no-cache
```

**Edit 2:**

After some fiddling, Firefox now throws the following error and not the connect error:

```
XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
```

QuickBlox SDK generates XML for communicating with its APIs. But as this is a third party SDK, I can't really fiddle with the requests it makes from its minified source.

The application is built with PHP 7.3/Laravel 5.8 and jQuery 3.

I request a solution to this issue and if possible an explanation of why it acts differently in these browsers. Thanks!

Comment: install Fiddler Proxy and install the Fiddler TLS certificate on all browsers and record Firefox until the error occurs, then record Chrome until the same place where FireFox got the error ,then compare the requests made by the 2 browsers, any noticable differences? (other than the `User-Agent` header, ofc)